# encrypted email id case insensitive MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to login with an case-insensitive email ID.My mail ID is stored in an encrypted format I am fetching from a database with something like the following query:

```
    $this->db->select('Name');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('emailId',"AES_ENCRYPT('{$emailId}','/*awshp$*/') ", FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
    return $result;
```

I am using binary but no use

Comment: What is wrong with your current query, and where are you checking the password or maybe token?

Comment: if i type small letters instead of capital letters it will take...how to add that logic in my query

Comment: Lowercase the input, and store the encrypted version of the lowercase email ID?

Comment: yes..is it possible to make caseinsenstive

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's have simple logic, While you sign up store hash value of email id after convert it to lowercase. and on login also convert it to lowercase.so if user enter email id in any case,encryption string match.

Comment: but code is updated with existed records its not possible to change

Comment: You can, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

AES encryption is a two-way algorithm, meaning you can recover the original value, so you can also update existing records that don't conform to the format you want to test.

After you run the update in the database, just apply the suggestions made by Tim Biegeleisen and you should be good to go.

Demo for updating existing records

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ->   email VARBINARY(256)
    ->   );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.31 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (email) VALUES 
    -> (AES_ENCRYPT('MiXeDcAsEdEmAiL@gmail.com','salt')),
    -> (AES_ENCRYPT('UPPERCASEDEMAIL@gmail.com','salt')),
    -> (AES_ENCRYPT('lowercasedemail@gmail.com','salt'));
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE t1 SET email = AES_ENCRYPT(LOWER(CAST(AES_DECRYPT(email,'salt') AS CHARACTER)),'salt');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT CAST(aes_decrypt(email,'salt') AS CHARACTER) lower_cased from t1;
+---------------------------+
| lower_cased               |
+---------------------------+
| mixedcasedemail@gmail.com |
| uppercasedemail@gmail.com |
| lowercasedemail@gmail.com |
+---------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

NB
Don't forget to change the update statement to match your column name and the value you use as a salt.